# Using iOS 9 / Xcode 7 Beta 5: Parse's "findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock" appears to never return

Tags: parse-platform, ios9, xcode7-beta5

I have code that works great in iOS 8, built using Xcode 6. It looks a little something like this:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"SomeClass"];
query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkElseCache;
[query orderByAscending:@"orderByField"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"Success!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```

When I upgrade my project to iOS 9 and try to run it from Xcode 7 Beta 5 using the Simulator, "findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock" doesn't ever return. I get no success, no error. Nothing.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you doing a breakpoint on NSError? Since last night my queries stopped return. Parse domain code 100.

Comment: Have you made sure you can run http/https websites?

Comment: I think it may occur because of Application Transport Security, you can read about it here: http://iosdevtips.co/post/121756573323/ios-9-xcode-7-http-connect-server-error